# How to enable ENTER button to send messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, send, message

How can I make the enter button instantly send a message with this script? I tried other solutions on the site, but I did not manage to code it myself.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#send_massage").click(function () {

        $("#send_massage").addClass("disabled");

        var variabila = $("#text-massage").val();
        var mesaj = "massage=" + variabila;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/chat.php",
            cache: false,
            data: mesaj,
            success: function (test) {
                $("#text-massage").val('');
                //$("#success").show("fast").delay(900).hide("fast");
                $("#success").html(test);
                $("#send_massage").removeClass("disabled");

            }
         });

     });

});
```

Comment: What programming language is this? Please add a tag to reflect that.

Comment: you should show your html code

Comment: Maybe you should put it in a form and catch the submit event, deping on if you use an input field or a textarea. Please add you html so we can give you a better answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `keyup` function to bind the event on an element (like the `document`) to your function. In the function, you check the `type` of the first parameter (`e`) and see if it is the `keyup` event. If it is, only continue if `enter` key was pressed (`keyCode` of `13`):

```
if(typeof e.type !== 'string' || (e.type == 'keyup' && e.keyCode != 13)) {
    return;
}
```

Try clicking on and typing in different keys in the example below. You'll see that both `enter` key and `click`ing on the button will cause call to be made:

```js
function sendMessage(e) {
    $("#send_massage").addClass("disabled");
    if(typeof e.type !== 'string' || (e.type == 'keyup' && e.keyCode != 13)) {
        return $('#status').html('no call');
    }
    $('#status').html('made call');
    var variabila = $("#text-massage").val();
    var mesaj = "massage=" + variabila;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/chat.php",
        cache: false,
        data: mesaj,
        success: function (test) {
            $("#text-massage").val('');
            //$("#success").show("fast").delay(900).hide("fast");
            $("#success").html(test);
            $("#send_massage").removeClass("disabled");

        }
    });

}
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#send_massage").click(sendMessage);
    $(document).keyup(sendMessage);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> WAIT..." id="send_massage" style="margin-right:6px;">SEND</button>
<div id='status'></div>
```

Comment: In my php file I have     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> WAIT..." id="send_massage" style="margin-right:6px;">SEND</button>. How can I implement the 2nd part into the code

Comment: @bagda391 Updated to use button instead.

Comment: If you hit run code snippet and then hit full page and press enter, it won't give any result

Comment: @bagda391 that's because the button is no longer in `focus` when hit `fullPage`

Comment: http://lockthepot.com right side SEND button not working :/. That's the code for the button

Comment: I changed event to act on document instead. It seems to work as long as the document is in focus now (click on page first)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code. This should be helpful for you

```js
function sendMessage(e) {
    $("#send_massage").addClass("disabled");
    if(typeof e.type !== 'string' || (e.type == 'keyup' && e.keyCode != 13)) {
        return $('#status').html('no call');
    }
    $('#status').html('made call');
    var variabila = $("#text-massage").val();
    var mesaj = "massage=" + variabila;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/chat.php",
        cache: false,
        data: mesaj,
        success: function (test) {
            $("#text-massage").val('');
            //$("#success").show("fast").delay(900).hide("fast");
            $("#success").html(test);
            $("#send_massage").removeClass("disabled");

        }
    });

}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).focus();
    $("#send_massage").click(sendMessage);
    $(document).keyup(sendMessage);

    $("input").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            sendMessage();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" style="width:300px;" placeholder="Please enter a value here and hit enter" />
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> WAIT..." id="send_massage" style="margin-right:6px;">SEND</button>
<div id='status'></div>
```

Comment: Script is good but when I start adding text the button's color fades away. Any solution for that?